# Possible to use the native facebook app to log into a mobile html5 app? On the iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, html, authentication, mobile

I'm trying to have my html5 site open the native iPhone Facebook app to authenticate users.

The site currently uses OAuth 2 on the server side - so it redirects everyone to the web version of Facebook. This is a problem because I dont want to force people to log in on a tiny keyboard.

Can you get the html5 app to open in Safari and authenticate through the native FB app?

If this is not possible with Facebook is it possible with Twitter apps? What is the experience like on android?

I do know that you can authenticate between a native iPhone app and the native Facebook app.

Comment: The keyboard in Safari is the same size as the one in the native Facebook app...

Comment: Ceejayoz, I'm assuming most people are perma-logged-in to the native facebook app. So they would never see the tiny keyboard. Any help on how to get the html5 app open the native app to authenticate w/o typing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this just use the boilerplate code in facebook developers section of the site and following the [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/) exactly... I have tried this and it worked for me you just need to find a way to connect your oAuth to this...

Comment: If your cache are wiped out and you first opening your web app without being logged in to facebook in mobile web-browser (let it be Safari) but having native facebook application logged in and running - this code DOES NOT WORKS for me.

Comment: @alakin just wondering whether the suggested solution is working or not? Have you tried it.

Comment: I just tried the solution and it definitely didn't work